# Proof that the Blancmange Curve is non-differentiable at the dyadic points of $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation

$\def\R{\mathbf{R}}$
$\def\Z{\mathbf{Z}}$
$\def\N{\mathbf{N}}$

**Background:** I'm self-studying real analysis from Abbott's book. This exercise is part of a section leading up to the proof that the blancmange function $g$ is continuous but no-where differentiable. (natural numbers assumed to be including $0$). I have so far proven that this function is continuous, and that it is not differentiable at $0,1/2$ and $1$.

**Exercise.** Prove that for any dyadic number $p/2^k$, where $p \in \Z$ and $k \in \N$, the function $g:\R \to \R$ given by $$ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^n}h(2^nx)} \\ h(x) =  \begin{cases}
        |x| & \text{if } x \in [-1,1]\\
        h(x+2) & \text{if } x<1\\
        h(x-2) & \text{if } x>1\\
\end{cases}$$
is not differentiable at that dyadic number.

*Proof idea.* Since the period of the sawtooth function $h$ is $2$, the points of non-differentiability are at $0,1,2,3,4..$ (and the negative integers but it's symmetric so I'll ignore the negative dyadics for now). For $h(2x)$, the period halves and hence isn't differentiable for every $p/2, \: p\in \Z$. So on, eventually for any $p/2^k$ there will be some $h(2^Nx),\: N \in \N$ where the period is so short that the points of non-differentiability are of the form $p/2^k$. And, for all $n \geq N$, $h(2^nx)$ will still be non-differentiable at $p/2^k$. The question now is, does a uniformly converging series of infinitely many functions, all non-differentiable at a certain point $y \in \R$, converge to a function that is also not differentiable at that point $y$? I feel like the answer must be true, but I can't make progress.

Further, the solution manual has a completely different method, one which I could not understand fully (portion boldened), $$x_m = 1/2^m$$
(b) Now let $x=p/2^k$ and consider
$$
g(x+x_m)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^n}h(2^n(x+1/2^m))} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^n}h(p2^{n-k}+2^{n-m})}.
$$
Because we are ultimately interested in what happens as $m\to \infty$, let's compute $g(x+x_m)$ assuming $m>k$.\
\indent If $n>m$ then because we are at a multiple of $2$ on the graph of $h(x)$ it follows that
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}h(p2^{n-k}+2^{n-m})=0.
$$
If $k<n\leq m$, then the periodicity of $h$ allows us to write
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}h(p2^{n-k}+2^{n-m}) = \frac{1}{2^n}h(2^{n-m})= \frac{1}{2^n}2^{n-m} = \frac{1}{2^m}.
$$
Finally, if $0\leq n\leq k$, **then $\mathbf{2^nx}$ and $\mathbf{2^{n-m}}$ fall on the same linear segment of $\mathbf{h(x)}$ and wet get**
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}h(p2^{n-k}+2^{n-m}) = \mathbf{\frac{1}{2^n}[h(p2^{n-k})\pm 2^{n-m}]} = \frac{1}{2^n}h(2^nx) \pm 1/2^m,
$$
where the choice of $+$ or $-$ depends on the value of $p$. Observing that $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{k}{(1/2^n)h(2^nx)}$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\frac{g(x+x_m)-g(x)}{x_m} &= \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{m}{1/2^nh(p2^{n-k}+2^{n-m})}-g(x)}{1/2^m} \\
&= \frac{\big[\sum_{n=k+1}^{m}{1/2^m}\big]+\bigg[\sum_{n=0}^{k}{(1/2^n)h(2^nx)\pm 1/2^m} \bigg]-g(x)}{1/2^m} \\
&= (m-k-1) + \sum_{n=0}^{k}{\pm1}\geq m-2k-1.
\end{align*}
Because this is unbounded as $m\to\infty$, it must be that $g'(x)$ does not exist for any dyadic rational point on the graph. The fact that we get $\infty$ from the right of for all of these limits is reflected in the graph of $g$ by the downward cusps that appear at every dyadic rational point.

Comment: Please do not rely on images (especially extensive images) to convey information not otherwise present in your post and which is necessary to understand your post. [See here for the reasons why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I would be happy to edit it, although I don't see a viable alternative. Typing out the solution above in LaTeX will take me atleast 90 minutes (not very good with LaTeX), and the point of difficulty is so minor compared to that. I suppose I could just link the images if anyone wishes to see them? I hope that would be alright.

Comment: It's the same problem. See the link to see why either linking to an image or posting an image and relying on it is bad practice: you are imposing (sometimes very heavily) on your potential readers.

Comment: Please suggest an alternative.

Comment: Get better with LaTeX, so you aren't imposing on the people from whom you are requesting free help. Or get someone to type it up for you.

Comment: Fair enough; converted everything into LaTeX. Side question: is it possible to import packages (like xcolor) into stackexchange? I tried it but it doesn't seem to work.